# Pointer to CCLayer from UIView

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have a little app up that has both CCLayer view and UIView. That works fine. I am simply trying to send a message to a reference of the layer so the Cocos2d CCLayer can receive the message. This seems simple and I'd think should work. I created a CCLayer pointer called "cocos" as an iVar and set it as this after creating the cocos view:

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene: [HelloWorldLayer scene]];

CCScene*tempscene=[[CCDirector sharedDirector] runningScene];
cocos=[tempscene.children objectAtIndex:0];
```

As this is a simple little test app with just one scene and layer, it should work. But the iVar `cocos` doesn't respond to any of the public methods in `HelloWorldLayer`. Any idea why?

UPDATE: I got it to work by simply re-arranging the code a bit. Not sure why it worked this way and not the prior way:

```
  CCScene*tempscene=[HelloWorldLayer scene];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene: tempscene];


cocos=[tempscene.children objectAtIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that the first bit of code didn't work for you is that `runWithScene:` doesn't immediately set the `runningScene` property of `CCDirector` to `[HelloWorldLayer scene]`.

Comment: any idea *when* `runningscene` becomes available?

Comment: I think once you call runWithScene, after that runningScene gets active because unless and until you really start a scene, No scene is available as running scene.

Comment: i did call it after runWithScene, as noted in my code, but apparently runningscene still did nothing

Comment: @andrewx I'm not familiar with the task loop for Cocos2D to answer that question.  I traced `runWithScene:` in the source code, but could only find that it sets the `nextScene_` instance variable equal to your `[HelloWorldLayer scene]`.  Therefore, I can only conclude that `runningScene` gets set to `nextScene_` in a different task.  By that, I mean that it happens after the function that contains your code is removed from the stack.  What you've noticed by experimenting with the order of your code verifies this.